# Number conversion in decimal fraction

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

980.85D convert to hexadecimal number = 3D4 . ??

how to solve the answer after the decimal point?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/fracToBaseK.html

Comment: but it's convert into hexadecimal..is it possible?

Comment: @Bills, See the subject under the title "How to Convert Arbitrary Floating Point to Base K"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place after the point is sixteenths, so think $.85 = \frac{x}{16}$.  So $x=16\cdot(.85)=13.6$.  So the first hex digit is $D$.  Then keep iterating this process (i.e., multiply the new decimal part by 16, and use the integer part of the result for the next hex digit) until the process terminates or you get repetition.

Comment: thanks but i could not understand after .85 what is the new decimal part?

Comment: The .6 is the new decimal part (from the 13.6).  The idea is that you have $\frac{.6}{16}$ left to deal with, and the next place value is $256^{\text{th}}$s.  So you have $\frac{.6}{16}=\frac{y}{256}$.  You multiply by 256 to find the value of $y$, which will give you a whole number part (your next hex digit) and a decimal part which you'll work with in the next step.

Comment: ohh i c thanks again but where the 256th came from?

Comment: $\frac{1}{256}$ is the second place value to the right of the hexadecimal point.

Comment: how about third and fourth place value to the right of the hexadecimal point?

Comment: Just keep multiplying by $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: ok got it..thanks ^^